# Why is my trigger not functioning correctly in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update, case

I have a trigger that fires when values in another table is updated.  Everything seems to be working correctly except breakeven_price is not giving me the value I expect.

Instead of returning the value of map or landed_cost times 100/85, its only returning the larger of map or landed_cost.  I'm new to triggers and sql generally, so I don't know if I'm using the trigger or case statements correctly.

```
BEGIN
IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
UPDATE s1.data
SET landed_cost = input.landed_cost, quantity = input.quantity, map = input.map, updated = now(),
breakeven_price =
CASE
WHEN input.map > input.landed_cost THEN (input.map*(100/85))
WHEN input.map <= input.landed_cost THEN (input.landed_cost*(100/85))
END
FROM s1.input
WHERE data.dist_sku = input.dist_sku;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
```

**EDIT** Trigger definition follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER pricing_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE s1.pricing_function();
```

Comment: Add the trigger definition to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver added

Comment: Do you realize that you are using int division, where (100/85) == 1 ?

Comment: And if is supposed to be `ON s1.data` you have 1) Set up an `UPDATE` recursion 2) Should have used `BEFORE UPDATE` and just returned a modified `NEW` record.  You need to spend some time here [plpgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: @jjanes I eventually realized that was the primary source of my woes.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the pointers.  I've spent the past few hours bouncing between the docs and examples.  Still learning SQL.  This particular issue has opened my eyes to how involved it can be.

Comment: As a side note: the `IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN` is not needed because the trigger is defined as `after update` so that IF condition will never be false.